# How do I swap ALT and the Windows key in one keyboard but not another?

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard, autohotkey, wireless-keyboard

I am running Bootcamp on a Macbook Air and I swapped Alt with the Windows key so ALT. I also have an external Windows Keyboard but this one has the keys swapped now too. 
I would like to swap the keys on the Macbook keyboard but not on the external one.

It seems this is not possible with AutoHotKey.

Comment: You can't.  You can only have a single keyboard layout active at any given time.

Comment: weird. it;s so easy on OSX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done with [AHKHID](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/38015-ahkhid-an-ahk-implementation-of-the-hid-functions/), however, it is not completely straightforward.

Essentially, you set up a hotkey as normal, then use AHKHID to detect which keyboard sent the input. Based on that, you either send the original key (equivalent to not remapping), or send the remapped key, depending on which keyboard it is.

However, AHKHID is considerably more complex than basic keyboard remapping, and I can't find any examples to demonstrate what I'm talking about.

As an alternative, you could use [LuaMacros](http://www.hidmacros.eu/forum/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=241), which natively supports multiple keyboards, although is not as full featured as AHK. For a simple remapping, it should probably suffice though.